How to detect the cause of a timeout exception?
I have a .NET 6 C# application that regularly performs some rest http requests in the background.
The app works most of the time, but on some machines I have a problem where it will randomly start getting timeout exceptions when performing an http call. This happens at random moments and typically lasts for a few minutes. It happens regardless of the client I use (I tried with the included .NET framework http client and also with RestSharp)
My question is: how can I determine the cause of the timeout? Because in my head this could really be anything:

Problem in the app
Problem in the OS
Problem in the network interface
Problem in the network
Problem of the remote host

...but all I get at code level is a System.TimeoutException with not much details to go on. Is there a way to determine what exactly caused a connection timeout?

The nature of this error does not let you get much details. You sent some data over your local network interface, you wait for reply but it did not come in time. Anything could have happened at any point between your machine and destination, but you cannot know what because, well, you didn't get a reply of any kind.

As you say, it could any number of reasons. You need to investigate them one by one. Start with a constant ping test, loggin when it drops. I would first suspect DNS (if the IP address changes then a cached HttpClient may not pick it up), then check the physical cabling, check the switches and routing,

On a second track, you may want to additionally fortify against flukes of that kind by hardening your code. Obvious choice would be Polly, ...
